# Facebook Pixel not firing on all pages

Tags: facebook-pixel

I have Facebook Pixel installed on a client's site but am running into a really weird issue.

I have the standard tracking code on the header for all the pages of the site.

`<script>!function (f, b, e, v, n, t, s) { if (f.fbq) return; n = f.fbq = function () { n.callMethod ? n.callMethod.apply(n, arguments) : n.queue.push(arguments) }; if (!f._fbq) f._fbq = n; n.push = n; n.loaded = !0; n.version = '2.0'; n.queue = []; t = b.createElement(e); t.async = !0; t.src = v; s = b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(t, s) }(window, document, 'script', 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js'); fbq('init', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'); fbq('track', 'PageView');</script> <noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none" src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=xxxxxxxxxxxxx&ev=PageView&noscript=1" /></noscript>`

And it's tracking pageviews correctly on almost every page, however, it is not tracking them on every page. When checking it with Pixel Helper I get the "We detected event code but the pixel has not activated for this event, so no information was sent to Facebook" message.

Further troubleshooting has led to three discoveries:

1. The pixel fires just fine on the subpages of the errant pages.

*Example:* clienturl.com/shop/order/products is not tracking page views but clienturl.com/shop/order/products/product is.

2. If I drop a Content Viewed event onto the problem pages, it tracks just fine. (This is my current work-around but is not sustainable long term).
3. Moving the tracking code for page views into the body rather than the head of the page does not fix the issue.

Does anyone have any experience with this happening that might be able to say why it's doing this?

The website is built on Sitefinity v11 for reference.

Comment: are there any js error in the console on the problematic page?

Comment: None that I've seen, other than "Manifest: Line: 2, column: 1, Syntax error." which is on every page.

Comment: I would put a breakpoint where the fbq track call is and see what's happening